# Spring Boot with JLink JRE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use jlink in Java 11 to create a minimized jre for a Spring Boot application. I have been able to get it to run with the full Java 11 jre, but am getting a stacktrace that I am having a hard time deciphering. I'm assuming the underlying cause is some kind of dependency conflict since it worked with the full jre and not the subset.

I am using spring-boot 1.5.19, and the modules I have currently included are: java.base, java.logging, java.instrument, java.sql, java.naming, and java.desktop.

Let me know what other information I can provide. Thanks!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'propertySourceBootstrapConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'propertySourceLocators'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consulPropertySourceLocator' defined in org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration$ConsulPropertySourceConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f7ea6c1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:187)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at ServiceConfiguration.main(ServiceConfiguration.java:34)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consulPropertySourceLocator' defined in org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration$ConsulPropertySourceConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f7ea6c1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f7ea6c1
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:466)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:349)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f7ea6c1
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:201)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f7ea6c1
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:73)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f7ea6c1.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer in this case is add the "jdk.unsupported" module to the argumentlist of modules for Jlink.

I base this on the fact that I had a similar problem (with a similar stackstrace) but while trying to build a custom JRE with a JDK17 and SpringBoot project. This is the Stack overflow post that helped me figure it out:
[NoSuchMethodException: springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332334/nosuchmethodexception-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-http-httpmessageconver)

Answer (score 0):

Java 11 is officially supported from Spring Boot 2.1.x

Comment: Yes, I'm aware its not officially supported at Spring 1, but since I was able to get it to run with the full java 11 jre I assumed I would be able to run it with jlink (even if I ended up including every module). Is this an invalid assumption?