# Is there a jboss-deployment-structure.xml equivalent for tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, wildfly

I need to migrate from jboss to tomcat, we have two war modules and need to declare the dependency between the two deployments in order for the libraries to be accessible by both the separate war files.

requirement arises due to licensing issues around the packaging of jar files in internal binaries.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do? Are you trying to make one (or more) JAR files visible to multiple web applications? Something else?

Comment: Due to licensing issues, I'm having to divide my single war file into two war files, primary war file containing the base code, and secondary war file containing the opensource jar files in the WEB-INF folder. 

I need to declare the dependency between primary and secondary war file at the time of the deployment. 

***This was being achieved using jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the wildfly deployment.

Comment: I am using tomcat and I am getting error no method found like mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332334/nosuchmethodexception-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-http-httpmessageconver as explained in the question , I am trying add module name="jdk.unsupported" , since there is no such file in tomcat I don't know where to add this . So please let me me know if there is any equivalent file in tomcat